# No rendered item Xamarin

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin

i have something that not work with my code 
I want it like a search bar that show me and save in a string\label a the place that i search on Gmaps, but the search bar is not showing
i tryed a guide on github : [link](https://github.com/leoCamilo/XamarinTutorial) but it not work well because i haven't any on the page
:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Firebase.Xamarin.Database;
using Firebase.Xamarin.Database.Query;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json ;
using System.Net.Http;
using Sport.Services;
```

namespace Sport
    {
    public partial class NewItemPage : ContentPage
    {
        private const string API_KEY = "String";

```
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public NewItemPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = Item = new Item();

        var stack = new StackLayout();
        var search = new SearchBar();
        var listView = new ListView();

        stack = new StackLayout();
        search = new SearchBar();
        listView = new ListView();

        stack.Children.Add(search);
        stack.Children.Add(listView);


        search.TextChanged += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var searchBar = (SearchBar)sender;
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" + searchBar.Text + "&types=geocode&key=" + API_KEY;

                var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                var predictionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GooglePlaceResult>(json);
                var srcList = new List<string>();

                foreach (var place in predictionList.predictions)
                {
                    srcList.Add(place.description);
                }

                listView.ItemsSource = srcList;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("error", "unknown error", "ok");
            }
        };

        Content = stack;
    }
    //metodi

    async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Item.Title == null || Item.Title.Equals("") || Item.Date == null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "You must insert a title and a date for your event", "Ok");
        }
        else
        {

            await DatabaseManager.DefaultManager.SaveTaskAsync(Item);
            await DisplayAlert("Item saved", "You saved the item " + Item.Title, "Ok");
            await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }
    }
    async void Choose_date(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Pagine.CalendarPage(Item, DataCamp));
    }

    public void Switch_toggled()
    {
        if (Swi.IsToggled)
        {
            TipoPost.Text = "Public";
            Item.IsPublic = true;
        }

        else
        {
            TipoPost.Text = "Private";
            Item.IsPublic = false;
        }
    }

    private void Picker_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("Time"))
            Item.Time = Picker.Time.ToString();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I think there may be a bug in Xamarin.Forms. I've tried a super simple example of a SearchBar and it runs fine on iOS, UWP and Android 5 and 6. On Android 7, however, the SearchBar doesn't appear.

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher you tink it will fix if i rewrite this part of code?

Comment: First you should see if you get the SearchBar if you run your code on an older version of Android and what happens on iOS and UWP, if you've implemented your project on those platforms.

Comment: SearchBar is visible or not even displayed on page. And which platform did you face to issue?